# What happens if I get my Canadian immigrant visa while I'm in the middle of a Master's degree in my home country?

Tags: visa, canada

All my family members including me, applied for immigration to Canada. I can't just sit and wait for the immigration visa, it might never come. We applied for the express visa.

So I applied for a master's degree, fully funded by my university and a third party. My university is certified by ABET and works with some US universities. However I don't think they have any relationship with Canadian universities.

My master's should take a year and a half, perhaps longer, since I'm busy, I have a full- time job and freelance projects. Some people in my country are receiving immigration visas within a year.

What would happen if I receive the immigration visa while doing my master's? Can I ask for additional time or would I have to quit and lose the tuition funds? Would I harm my family or postpone their immigration?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Canadian visa system, but I think that "I have to finish a Masters degree" is a good reason for them to extend a deadline. It would allow you to enter the country better-prepared to enter the workforce or Canadian academia. But by no means is that a definite answer, I just understand your motivations. Good luck and I hope someone who knows more about Canada can help you!

Comment: Masters in three semesters, next to a fulltime job *and* freelance projects? Wow.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique thats exactly why I applied for a masters, I don't need it in my country I'm already a senior, but wanted to get more points on the immigration system

Comment: @Karl it might take longer as explained in my question than 3 semesters. But what can I do? If im lucky i'd be able to stop taking freelance for a while, but I have to be prepared for the worst case scenario. Plus I have to make extra money, you can't immigrate if you don't have extra money. Life is hard.

Comment: In the US, at least, it's possible to "adjust" from a nonimmigrant status to that of a permanent resident if one becomes eligible for PR status while in the country.  I suspect that Canada has a similar provision.  If so, you should not need to quit your studies.

Comment: @phoog thank you I'll research that to see if it's possibe in canada

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you aren't in Canada yet? and you need to remain outside Canada in order to finish the degree?

Comment: @krubo yes and not affect my family or lose my immigration visa once i get the Masters

Comment: @krubo thanks for asking that. I totally misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory,You don't have to settle in Canada immediately after you immigrate.
I believe that it's quite common that you can just enter Canada border once(Landing) using your immigrate visa before expiration for a short stay to get your PR legal status and paperwork done. After that , you can return to your school immediately to finish your study.

The only catch is you will need a PR card to enter Canada next time . You will need an address in Canada to receive it. (You could have a family member to get that for you or use another special document from CIC to enter)

You should google a little online or go CIC site directly

Comment: In the US, the endorsed immigrant visa functions as a temporary green card for one year, so the newly-arrived permanent resident can leave immediately after arrival.  Does Canada not have some analogous system?

Comment: Crossing-border from US by land via private vehicle could use "landing paper"  with additional docs to enter Canada [ref link](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/prepare-life-canada/border-entry.html) .  For entry via air or boat, it possible to apply for a  [PRTD](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5529-applying-permanent-resident-travel-document.html)  to back to Canada